# ¿de que se llenan los arrays cuando no se inicializan?

Tags: java, array

> Si no me equivoco, que es lo más probable, un array no inicializado de Strings se llena de null, uno de Int se llena de 0 y un boolean de false. Y el de []char de que se llena?

Comment: ¿Has intentado al menos leer la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) al respecto?

Comment: En primer lugar busqué información aquí, que siempre es mucho  más cálida que la API, pero no me quedó claro, así que traté varias pruebas en el IDE y conseguí lo que pretendía llenando el char array de cosas y después sustituyéndolas. NO leí esa documentación que refieres, que aún sigo siendo profano pero me la guardo y en lo sucesivo buscaré en esa página que parece ser la de referencia. gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sí con no inicializado te refieres a algo como esto:

```
public char[] chars;
```

Entonces el array es `null` y no está lleno de nada, porque un array no es un primitivo, sino un objecto (por más que este compuesto de primitivos).

Ahora, si te refieres a algo así:

```
public char[] chars = new char[5];
```

Entonces sí, ese array se llena con char 0, o unicode \u0000, que es el character de control null y no tiene representación (se vé como si fuera `""`, aunque no es lo mismo que un string vacío).